# How to compare the number of matching words in two cells? Excel / Google Sheets

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to create a formula in Excel or Google Sheets that compares two cells with text values and returns the number of words that match.

Example:
Cell A2 = This is an apple
Cell B2 = This was a rotten apple
Value returned: 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Excel 365 you could do:

```
=SUM( --ISNUMBER( MATCH( UNIQUE( TEXTSPLIT( A2, " "), 1 ),
                         UNIQUE( TEXTSPLIT( B2, " "), 1 ),
                         0 ) ) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[google sheet sample_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im2pO.png)

[google sheet sample_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gASQS.png)

Since you didn't mention if it counts or not when a same word appears more than one time in the string, here are two samples, where sample_1 do count duplicates, and sample_2 don't:

```
// sample_1:
=ArrayFormula(SUM(INT(
 LAMBDA(COL,ROW,
  REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(ROW))&"","[0-9]+",COL)=ROW
 )(SPLIT($A$2," "),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT($B$2," ")))
)))

// sample_2:
=ArrayFormula(SUM(INT(
 LAMBDA(COL,ROW,
  REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(ROW))&"","[0-9]+",COL)=ROW
 )(UNIQUE(SPLIT($A$2," ")),TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(SPLIT($B$2," "))))
)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most elegant solution but it works **as the question was originally posted**.

```
= query(query(transpose(split(A2 & " " & B2, " ")),
        "Select count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1) '' "),
    "Select count(Col1) where Col1 != 1 group by Col1 label count(Col1) 'Total matching' ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I get error "That function isn't valid"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Je5zcShC9FxcN29uFro-2mvP2ov78ZPZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You've added the tag: `google-sheets-formula`, therefore my solution works for Google Sheets